# From conditional independence to independence

Tags: probability, independence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, {\bf P})$ be a probability space. Let $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ be two events and $Z$ a random variable with values in a nice space $(S, \mathcal{S})$. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $Z$ (i.e.,  independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Z$). It is known that $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily independent.

However, it seems possible to show that if $A$ and $B$ are themself independent of $Z$, then $A$ and $B$ are also independent. Is the proof below correct ? If yes could you give some intuition of why ? Thanks a lot !

${\bf Proof:}$ Denote by ${\bf P}( . | Z = z)$ the regular conditional probability of ${\bf P}$ given $Z$ and by ${\bf P}(Z \in dz)$ the law of $Z$. We have
$${\bf P}(A \cap B) = {\bf P}((A \cap B) \cap \{Z \in S\}) = \int_S{\bf P}(A \cap B | Z = z){\bf P}(Z \in dz)$$
$$= \int_S{\bf P}(A | Z = z){\bf P}(B | Z = z){\bf P}(Z \in dz)$$
$$= \int_S{\bf P}(A){\bf P}(B){\bf P}(Z \in dz) = {\bf P}(A){\bf P}(B).$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by a "nice space"?

Comment: How did you get the last-but-one equality?

Comment: @littleO Hello. A nice space $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space such that there exists a one-to-one map $\phi$ from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ both measurable. (see p. 51 in Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples, 4th edition). The main utility is that we can define the regular conditional probabilities for such spaces (see Theorem 5.1.9 p.231 and Exercise 5.1.1.16 p.232 in the same book).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hello. I think this follows from the independence of $A$ and $B$ from $Z$, but this might be wrong.

Comment: The proof looks good to me. If you want to avoid regular conditional probabilities, you could just look at $P(A\cap B)=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_A\mathbf{1}_B\mid Z]]$ but the proof is identical to yours.

Comment: @kantadou your proof seems OK.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, StefanHansen Thank you for your help !